# Office.js add-in display dialog dynamic size

Tags: outlook, office-js

I am making an add-in for outlook with dialogues using the `displayDialogAsync` method.

The problem is that if the main window has a small size the dialog will also be small, because the width and height is a percentage of the main window, and the content will not fit.

Is it possible to know the size of the main window, so I can use that to calculate how big the dialog should be?

I have tried with `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()` but that returns the height and width of the box the add-in buttons are located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display dialog only supports percentages, and the feature you requested is currently not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34701499-allow-dialogs-to-be-sized-with-pixels-instead-of-o). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: UserVoice links are broken